# Function parameter type based on value of another parameter

Tags: typescript

I have TypeScript function, that has 2 parameters

- type: `"user" | "book"`,
- data: `User` if type is `"user"`, `Book` if type is `"book"`.

Is there any way to get the correct `data` type based on value of `type` parameter without type assertion (`(data as Book).author`)? Here is [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN7JHAWwgC5l0wpQBzAbmQF8AoUSWRFAIQHsuBrHPIRJkK1OnACuYABZcopcpRC0GjMAE8ADigCycTQBUtEdMgC8AiZnlprdAEY9epbnzpMN25Ee0A5IebIvBDqXDDIeobG6HSMjAhcIOTI0nAgACYANlgWADw%20KBAAHpAZpgX%20RAB8ABSewgUANMjpcGBwpJEF6ADaBQC6AJTmVTiMyBPIwOF1xuZmFgBEjnyLw9jjk1sJSVzZAHSZXFQ1re37kjJyg3QA9LfIAKJQUHLNZ3DICGnI9iiOMlsWDS6WQrn4EAAbhAQMgAO7AQE7dKI4CJZBwRzQ-abCZMehAA).

```
interface User { name: string; }
interface Book { name: string; author: string; }
type MapTypes = { user: User; book: Book; }
type TypeName = keyof MapTypes; 

const handler = <Type extends TypeName>(type: Type, data: MapTypes[Type]) => {
    if (type === "book") {
        console.log(data.author); // Error, data is not typed as Book, but still as User | Book
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAyp1m) work for you? You can create all possible arguments from the type map and then destructure the tuple in the function body.

Comment: @hittingonme Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. Can you please create answer, so I can mark it as accepted solution?

Answer (score 0):

We can create all possible arguments from the type map and then destructure the tuple in the function body.

```
interface User { name: string; }
interface Book { name: string; author: string; }
type MapTypes = { user: User; book: Book; }

type PossibleArgs = {
    [K in keyof MapTypes]: [type: K, data: MapTypes[K]];
}[keyof MapTypes];

const handler = (...args: PossibleArgs) => {
    const [type, data] = args;

    if (type === "book") {
        console.log(data.author); // Works fine now
    }
}
```

Originally answered by **vera.** in comments.